# Tengo un problema en mi login, a veces no me lee los datos

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un login con php y mysql, pero hay ocasiones en que no me deja entrar hasta que copie los datos directo de la base de datos, practicamente tengo que abrir el phpmyadmin buscar el usuario y pegarlo en el login para que vuelva a funcionar, cabe mencionar que estoy trabajando con un hosting.

```php
<?php

session_start();
// Datos para conectar a la base de datos.
$servidor      = "localhost";
$nombreusuario = "xxxx";
$password      = "xxxx";
$db            = "xxxxx";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $nombreusuario, $password, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$email    = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$email'
 AND password = '$password'");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if ($row == 1) {
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    
    header("Location: Panel.php");
} else {
    
}

?>
<div id="login-page">
   <div class="container">
      <form class="form-login" method="post">
         <h2 class="form-login-heading">INICIAR SESIÓN</h2>
         <div class="login-wrap">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="Usuario" autofocus>
            <br>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-theme btn-block" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Continuar</button>
            <hr>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Te falta el ``action=""`` en la definición del ``<form>``

Comment: Quizás es un problema de **visión** y estás leyendo mal el usuario o la contraseña cuando los tecleas.  Por ejemplo, aquí que lees?  "IlalaIal" ... como ves algunos caracteres pueden confundirse (aparecen `i` en mayúscula y `l` en minuscula en ese texto `IlalaIal`) y quizás es tan simple como eso (no tiene pinta de ser otra cosa) y confundes algún caracter.

Comment: lo que pasa es que no solo me ha pasado a mí, si no a otros usuarios tambien, por eso me causa duda

Comment: Pues mira que no tengas espacio en blanco al final del usuario o la contraseña y cuando lo copias del phpmyadmin te los llevas bien.  Quizás por lo que sea se guardan con espacios.

Comment: Lo peor de todo esto es guardar una password tal cual en la base de datos, lo cual supone un gravísimo problema de seguridad. Deberías usar `password_hash` para guardar la clave y `password_verifify` para verificar que es la clave correcta. Y en cuanto a las consultas, usar consultas preparadas. Si quieres verificar que no hay espacios de más o cosas así, puedes hacer un `var_dump` de la password recibida y crear temporalmente una variable con la clave real y probarla también con `var_dump`. De todos modos, la seguridad está  seriamente comprometida en tu código y no deberías ignorarlo.

Comment: como podría aplicar lo que mencionas? tienes un ejemplo o algo? así como lo explicas no sirve de mucho